# new react user creating React App not working?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am a new react user and I have no idea how to fix it here, create react app is not working I have also tried reinstalling node Js. Npm version: 8.12.2 node version: v16.15.1 and I also tried reinstalling Npx The error is coming with some Error:

> spawn UNKNOWN, Errno: -4094, code: 'UNKNOWN', Syscall: 'spawn'

please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try either disabling (or uninstalling) your antivirus and running the command again, or running you command prompt with elevated permissions (administrator).